# Tajimas D for sequences of different length

Tags: r, fasta, dna-sequence

I am trying to use adegent in R for calculating the Tajima's D. I have a DNA.bin object containing my sequences from different populations. The sequences are of varying length because of the SNP and indels in them. I get the following error when I run the tajima.test function:

Error in as.matrix.DNAbin(x) : 
  DNA sequences in list not of the same length.

How could one deal with calculating Tajima's D for sequences of different length?

Here's what I did so far:

```
   x <- structure(c("55548", "43297", "35309", "34468", "AATTCAATGCTCGGGAAGCAAGGAAAGCTGGGGACCAACTTCTCTTGGAGACATGAGCTTAGTGCAGTTAGATCGGAAGAGCA", "AATTCCTAAAACACCAATCAAGTTGGTGTTGCTAATTTCAACACCAACTTGTTGATCTTCACGTTCACAACCGTCTTCACGTT", "AATTCACCACCACCACTAGCATACCATCCACCTCCATCACCACCACCGGTTAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACTCTGAACTGTAAACCCAGTC", "AATTCTATTGGTCATCACAATGGTGGTCCGTGGCTCACGTGCGTTCCTTGTGCAGGTCAACAGGTCAAGTTAAGATCGGAAGA"), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))
   y <- t(sapply(strsplit(x[,2],""), tolower))
   my.dnabin <- as.DNAbin(y)
   tajima.test(my.dnabin)
```

Comment: Are you using `tajima.test` from `pegas`? There isn;t one in `adegenet`. Your DNA sequences should be aligned within the DNA.bin object, so they should all be the same size. Try including some data in the question

Comment: @jeremycg: Yes, I meant the tajima.test from pegas. Please check the edited question now :-) 
I didn't understand your sentence "Your DNA sequences should be aligned within the DNA.bin object, so they should all be the same size." Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tajima's D uses pairwise comparisons of nucleotides, and thus requires that your [DNA is properly aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) before running. Yours is not at present, so you get an error. Most DNA.bin methods assume your DNA is aligned - this should be your first step.

To align your DNA, try the `clustal` command from ape - you will need clustal installed. I've used [clustal omega](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalo/) as I don't think R is the best way to do DNA alignments.

You will get an aligned DNA sequence which is now suitable for Tajima's D (note the gaps, used to align the sequences):

```
x <- structure(c("55548", "43297", "35309", "34468", 
                 "AATTCAATGCTCGGGAAGCAAGGAAAGCT---GGGGACCAACTTCTCTTGGAGACATGAGCTTAGTGCAGTTAGATCGGAAGAGCA-----------------------",
                 "AATTCCTAAAACACCAATCAAGT----TG---------GTGTTGCTAATTTCAACACCAACTTGTTGAT------------CTTCACGTTCACAACCGTCTTCACGTT-",
                 "-----AATTCACCA-------------CCACCACTAGCATACCATCCACCT--CCATCACCACCACCGGTTAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACTCTGAACTGTAAACCCAGTC",
                 "AATTCTATTGGTCATCACAATGGTGGTCCGTGGCTCACGTGCGTTCCTTGTGCAGGTCAACAGGTCAAGTTAAGATCGGAAGA--------------------------"), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))
```

and now your test will run:

```
   y <- t(sapply(strsplit(x[,2],""), tolower))
   my.dnabin <- as.DNAbin(y)
   tajima.test(my.dnabin)
$D
[1] -5.624054

$Pval.normal
[1] 1.865271e-08

$Pval.beta
[1] 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me learn that Tajimas D can be calulated with sequences aligned! :-)